# Installing 32bit rpm in 64bit machine

Tags: centos, centos6, yum, rpm

First of all I know this is a complete mess but due to some developer legacy code(hard coded value),I am forced to install 32 bit rpm on 64 bit machine.

```
       cat /etc/redhat-release
       CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

Problem is when I am trying to install any package its pulling both 32 as well as 64bit RPM,I am aware of the fact that

```
                   multilib_policy=all(by default)
```

so it try to pull both package, and as this is a 64bit machine even setting multilib_policy=best will not help,so I try to exclude it in yum.conf using

```
                      exclude=*.x86_64
```

but still no luck.Any help is appreciated.

```
         yum install gcc
        Setting up Install Process
       Resolving Dependencies
       --> Running transaction check
       ---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.4.7-3.el6 will be updated
      ---> Package gcc.i686 0:4.4.7-4.el6 will be an update
```

Comment: For many packages there is no harm in having the 32-bit and 64-bit rpm's installed at the same time.  Did having both packages installed cause a problem for you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I know disk space now a days increase in leap and bound but still being a sys admin we always need to consider disk space as a factor,I believe there is no point of installing 64bit rpm if no application is going to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Include `.i686` along with the package name to install the 32bit package. To install the 64bit package you would use `.x86_64`.

```
yum install gcc.i686
```

Answer (score 0):

"Will be updated" means you already have the package installed. If you want to not have it download both versions, uninstall the one that you don't want. Don't want GCC 64-bit? Use `yum remove gcc.x86_64`.

Comment: Nathan,I think I have a much better option,to list and clean duplicate packages                                                                   package-cleanup --dupes
package-cleanup --cleandupes